# how to drop rows on a pandas dataframe with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

```py
    import pandas as pd

data = {'col1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'col2': [1, 177, 62876, 83036, 108504],
        'col3': [7765, 177, 62876, 83036, 108504],
        'col4': ['7,765', 'Non-Bitter', 'Non-Bitter', 'Non-Bitter', 'Non-Bitter'],
        'col5': ['NaN', '2_Fnb', '3_Fnb', '4_Fnb', '5_Fnb'],
        'col6': ['1_Fnb', '2_Fnb', '3_Fnb', '4_Fnb', '5_Fnb'],
        'col7': ['O(C([H])([H])C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])[H]',
                 'O=C([H])C([H])([H])[H]',
                 'O(C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])OC([H])([H])C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])[H]',
                 'O(C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])OC([H])([H])C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])[H]',
                 'O(C([H])([H])C([H])([H])C([H])=C([H])C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])C([H])(C([H])([H])[H])[H]'],
        'col8': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        'col9': ['CCOC(C)OCC', 'CC=O', 'CCCCOC(C)OCCc1ccccc1', 'CC(C)CCOC(C)OCCC(C)C', 'CCOC(C)OCCC=CCC'],
        'col10': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'StandardizeStereo\nStandardizeStereo_ChiralFlag', 'NaN', 'StandardizeStereo\nStandardizeStereo_ChiralFlag'],
        'col11': [5.0645, 1.67, 8.31033, 8.24664, 8.7538],
        'col12': [5.0, 0.0, 7.05817, 11.0, 9.0,0,0,0],
        'col13': [4.92, 0.0, 6.36993, 10.92, 8.65999],
        'col14': [5.01386, 1.4863, 6.85916, 8.19952, 8.50578],
        'col15': [8.0, 3.0, 16.0, 14.0, 12.0],
        'col16': [7.0, 2.0, 16.0, 13.0, 11.0],
        'col17': [7.0, 1.0]
```

i am trying to drop rows where the value zero occurs more than 50 percent of the time(or 50 percent of the time) with the following code:

```python
df2.drop(df2[df2.astype(bool).sum(axis=1) >= df2.shape[1]*0.5].index, inplace=True)
```

however when i run it, it drops All the rows. i have tried a couple different variations and made sure that each column is of a numeric type but the result is the same.

the only issue i thought of is maybe im counting NAN values as zero but i cant figure out how to get around that i tried the following code and got the same result:

````python
df4.drop(df4[(df4 == 0) | df4.isnull()].astype(int).sum(axis=1) >= df4.shape[1]*0.5].index, inplace=True)
```the desired result is a dataframe to simply drop the rows where the above stated condition is met 
any help is appreciated
````

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This should give the desired result:

```python
df2 = df2.drop(index=df2[df2.eq(0).sum(axis=1).ge(len(df2.columns) / 2)].index)
```

Sample input:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  0  1  2
3  0  0  1  1  3
4  0  1  1  1  4
5  1  1  1  1  5
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
3  0  0  1  1  3
4  0  1  1  1  4
5  1  1  1  1  5
```

**Here's another example:**

Sample input:

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5
0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2 NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
3 NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.0
4 NaN  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
5 NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0
6 NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0
```

Output:

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5
0 NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4 NaN  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  3.0
5 NaN  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  4.0
6 NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  5.0
```

Comment: first off thank you for replying.
i tried your code and still got the same result which is all the rows of my df are being dropped(i check this with df.shape before and after).
i just rechecked df.dtypes and the rows are float64 could that be influencing the result?

Comment: I don't think that's it. I tried adding a row of all NaN values (which means each column ha a NaN and therefore has type float64), and it still works for me. You can see the output in my updated answer.

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual input you're seeing the problem with?

Comment: i tried to add a code example of the data frame above.
i am new here so please excuse me if its not properly formatted

Comment: Thanks. Note that col12 has 8 rows and col17 has 2 rows, whereas all other columns have 5 rows. This causes an error when I try to create a dataframe from `data` in your question. If I ignore those columns, I still don't see any rows with a majority of zero values. So the code in my answer doesn't drop any rows.